# Why does my macro crash when I save the file to a different location?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an Excel file in which a VBA macro loads data into a Userform.

When I copy the file to a different location the macro works fine. But if I then save the file to that location (as an Excel Macro-Enabled workbook), close it and reopen it, the macro crashes when I try to run it.

What could be causing it to crash? The macro does not make use of any external workbooks - it simply loads data from the file into the userform. I'm stumped as to what the cause is. I notice that when I save it, the file size is a bit different than the original (10 kb)

Sample code from the macro:

```
Public Sub LoadButton_Click()  

'Policy Information  
ZoneLatitudeTextBox.Text = Sheets("Saved Policy Values").Cells(2, 2)  
ZoneLongitudeTextBox.Text = Sheets("Saved Policy Values").Cells(3, 2)  
TownClassComboBox.Text = Sheets("Saved Policy Values").Cells(4, 2)
```

Comment: What's your code? It's pretty hard to help debug when we aren't sure what you're doing.

Comment: Added some code above

Comment: What's the error? Why do you need to "save it to a new location" if copying it works fine?

Comment: Excel just crashes without telling me what the error is. I need to save it to a new location so that other people can use it repeatedly. Saving it elsewhere corrupts the file somehow.